# WooCommerce - Checkout Fields for Specific Product

Tags: woocommerce, checkout

I'm looking to show the order notes for only one specific product and hide for all other products. Seems simple but I've struggled to piece code together to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code adding in `functions.php` of your theme file and replace to your `$product_id = 282;`.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enable_order_notes_field', '__return_false' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'bbloomer_find_product_in_cart' );

function bbloomer_find_product_in_cart() {

  $product_id = 282;

  $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id );
  $in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );

if ( $in_cart ) {

 add_filter( 'woocommerce_enable_order_notes_field', '__return_true' );

}

}
```